# Conditional Criteria for InfoPath

Tags: infopath

I have a infopath form for a registration list in SharePoint 2010. The form provides 3 different hotel options that participants can choose. These hotel fields are "Yes/No" type. Once a hotel receives 20 "yes" then I want that hotel option to be hidden on the InfoPath form. I know how to hide a field in InfoPath using rules.

I need help in creating a new rule, which will check the list for number of hotel options, and if any hotel has 20 "yes" or bookings, then InfoPath should hide that hotel field.

I am using SharePoint 2010 and InfoPath Designer 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Create a secondary data connection to the list and retrieve items for each hotel and set a rule which will count the number of items returned for that hotel and based on the return count > 20  hide/show the hotel field.

Be careful while getting data from list since you will need huge data , so try to be more precise and retrieve items only you need with single column alone. ( Either retrieve all items and filter in conditions or set the query field of data connection and then query data connection afterwards).

Let me know if it helps you.